# Ionic2 : How to set up css in single page

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to **Ionic2** and just a learner.

I just want to set up css files in the single page, not globally.

I know how to set up css file globally, but I don't know how to set up locally.

When update the file `app/theme/app.core.scss`, it's fine. But it is global set up.

How can I set up css locally on single page?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more what exactly you want?

Comment: @Nirus Thank you for your response. Problem Sovled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ionic2` demo? You can simple defined `.scss` file with page.

See attach image for reference.

[image: css for each page]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have misunderstood css in Ionic2. Thank you for your answering.